# c# FirestoreDB Winforms - trouble getting access to firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, winforms, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get access to my firebase Firestore however I am having issues and I'm not finding a lot of documentation on it. I have some experience using it with Android Studio however C# WinForms seems to be a different kind of beast in terms of getting started.

Where I'm at:

1. I've created a firestore project in firebase and created the collection: "Users" with one document in it.
2. In my visual studio, I have installed `Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1`
3. in my winforms file, I have this:

```
 private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string projectId = "my-projectId-from-my-settings-on-Firebase";

            FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);

            CollectionReference collectionReference = db.Collection("Users");

        }
```

I end up getting this error and I don't know why

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Core, Version=1.44.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

It breaks at this line: `FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);`

I am trying to follow this page here: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/

I'm using a mac but I'm running visual studio in parallels for windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#c) on Firebase docs. If you looked into it and it seems that you have to set up an environment variable for path to credential file.

I would try to go through this "get started guide" before.

I hope it will help!

Comment: so I tried following that guide but it wasn't working. I ended up stumbling upon this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptEtTNQ0dXg) and it works for me.